# Find all documents where a sub-array element matches "nan"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a bunch of documents that look like this

```
{
  "coordinates": [[1, 2], [nan, nan]  ]
}
```

I would like to filter and find all documents where one of those arrays contains `nan` values like in the example.

Answer (score 1):

**[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)** with `$in` query will also filter, check below query

```
db.collection.find({"coordinates":{"$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{"$in":["nan"]}}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have pairs in your inner arrays then

```
db.yourColl.find({coordinates: [NaN, NaN]})
```

should do the job

Comment: This will fail if only one element in the sub-array is NaN

Comment: Therefore I wrote if you have pairs ... The sample data shows it like that so I gave this answer.